# What is the correct terminology for the process of reading a simple config and creating data structures corresponding to the data we acquired?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, tokenize, terminology

```
Reading is defined as interpreting and understanding a written material.

Parsing is defined as analyzing relationships between words in a written material and grouping those words according to underlying grammar.
```

My question is, what is the correct terminology for the process of reading a simple config and creating data structures corresponding to the data we acquired, parsing or reading?

I read many places about this distinction but I wasn't able to arrive at a conclusion by myself. In many places these terms used in an interchangeable manner. For example:

```
1. Reading a Lisp object means parsing a Lisp expression in textual form and producing a corresponding Lisp object.
From <http://zvon.org/other/elisp/Output/SEC256.html> 


2. In the programming language Lisp, the reader or read function is the parser which converts the textual form of Lisp objects to the corresponding internal object structure.
From <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_reader>
```

So I have a mixed understanding for parsing (grouping tokens in to syntactical elements) and creating data structures by using the elements we get from parsing (interpreting). I would much appreciate clear explanation of these topics and advision of sources where I can make further research about these topics.

Comment: Pandas calls it `read`, in JS JSON uses `parse`, `doten`uses `parse`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single “correct terminology” without context. Words are used with different meanings in different contexts.

Often when discussing computing, “reading” means retrieving data, and “parsing” means analyzing a string of characters or other symbols relative to some rules for their grammar and interpretation. However, these meanings should not be taken as absolute; the words can be used in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that Lisp is peculiar to that regard, and is probably *not* a good starting point - precisely because most languages aren't Lisp.

Usually, in a typical compiler, things work (roughly ...) as follows:

- Your compiler gets a file which is, for all intent and purposes, just a bunch of characters at this point.
- Now, there is a first phase called lexical analysis (or *tokenization*), which "breaks" those characters into pieces with *some* meaning attached (e.g., upon reading `int x = 13`, it will produce four tokens, something like `[("int", TYPE_KEYWORD), ("x", VAR_IDENTIFIER), ("=", ASSIGN_SYMBOL), ("13", NUMBER)]`. At this point, there are no real checks occuring as long as you are not producing *complete* garbage: the lexer would typically be happy with `x x 13 = = x` as input. It might however reject `abc"def` if you can't have quotes `"` inside a variable name !
- Then, and only then, is the time where the compiler performs what it usually refered to as *parsing*: the tokens produced in the lexing phase are matched to a grammar, to see if "things have a normal shape"; so `= x = 34 int` will be rejected, but `int abcd = "twelve"; abcd["hello" + 25.76] = 5;` will not.
- The parser (which does the previous phase) will typically produce a *parse tree*, saying roughly what the different elements are (*e.g.* function definition, with some arguments, an assignement to some variable, a while-loop etc). This really is some information *only available to this compiler*, and this tree only exists for the compilation phase; it does not exist in the compiled code, etc. In particular, you can have a compiler written in a language A which compiles a language B, and the parse tree would be a data structure of the language A.
- There are more phases occuring in compilation, but as far as we are concerned, this is it. Of course, much more needs to be done (analysis to check *e.g.* the program type correctness, checking that all functions being called actually have a definition, etc etc, and finally producing a compiled version of the code !), but parsing is over at this point.

You can have an example of the grammar I mentionned above for [Python's function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), where you see how a "valid" function definition has to match some "shape", defined by the grammar, itself being defined in terms of tokens (~ groups of characters)

The thing with Lisp is the following:

- Lisp code is, more or less like any other language, written in files.
- However, what happens in (Common) Lisp is that this file is "read" (as if) *by a Common Lisp function* called `read`. This function reads characters, and returns *a Lisp object* (typically, a list, with symbols, numbers and nested lists, etc). That is, if your file contains *the characters* `(list 10 "abcd")` (which is 16 characters), `read` will return *the Lisp list* `(list 10 "abcd")`, a list of length three containing a symbol, an integer and a string.
- Now, *that Lisp object is the thing being evaluated* (and compiled, if needed). Said differently, the grammer and therefore the semantics of the language are defined *in terms of Lisp objects*, not in terms of characters/tokens.

You can see what I mean if you check [Common Lisp's reference for function definition](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm): no characters are being referenced, only symbols, lists and other Lisp objects.

Of course, a Lisp compiler will still have to work: determine what symbols correspond to what bindings, check that the grammar is actually respected, deal with memory and what not, but the reading/parsing phase is fundamentally distinct. In particular, the sentence

> Reading a Lisp object means parsing a Lisp expression in textual form and producing a corresponding Lisp object.

has no equivalent in other languages. There is no "corresponding Python object" to the bunch of characters `foo = bar[42]`. There is one, on the other hand, for Lisp's characters `(setf foo 42)` -- a list of length 3, containing two symbols and a number.

Comment: It certainly has an equivalent in some other languages. Postscript and Forth spring to mind.